# Truncate the string after numeric characters

Tags: r, regex, string

```
a = c("AZ_UA-20170127012114_001.hl7", "AZ_UA-20170127012050_001.hl7",        
"AZ_YRMC_20170127_06_001.hl7")
```

How can I write the regular expression to get expected output is as follows:

```
c("AZ_UA-", "AZ_UA-",  "AZ_YRMC_")
```

I do know `gsub` function but always get stuck in the regular expression. If there is a detailed description of the regular expression, it would be helpful (I do not think the one in R help file is friendly to beginners.)

Comment: `gsub("^((?:[^_-]*[_-]){2}).*", "\\1", a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `regmatches` + `gregexpr` approach:

```
a = c("AZ_UA-20170127012114_001.hl7", "AZ_UA-20170127012050_001.hl7",        
      "AZ_YRMC_20170127_06_001.hl7")

unlist(regmatches(a, gregexpr("^[-A-Z_]+", a)))

# [1] "AZ_UA-"   "AZ_UA-"   "AZ_YRMC_"
```

`gregexpr` gives a list of starting and ending positions of matches, while `regmatches` extracts *only* the matched text from `a` using the output from `gregexpr`.

The `^` symbol in regex means *starting from the beginning*. The first `-` inside `[-A-Z_]` matches a *dash*, while the second dash (between `A` and `Z`) is a way to express *from A to Z*. Because of this latter property, you have to put a `-` on the first position right after `[` if you want to match a `-` as is. Finally, `_` matches an *underscore* and the `+` sign means match the previous character class *one or more times*. So `"^[-A-Z_]+"` matches all dashes, capital letters or underscores starting from the beginning one or more times.

Different from @d.b's approach, this approach directly extracts what you want, instead of removing what you don't want.